# Traffic cone detection and mapping

Tags: slam, camera, lidar

as part of formula student car racing I need a SLAM algorithm that will recognize cones and will build a map (there will be a few laps therefore map is needed for optimal path).  The cones are of known size. What is my best option in your opinion to choose sensors out of the following 3:

1. 2 cameras that will use geometry to determine the distance of the cones from the vehicle.
2. 1 camera that will use an estimation and the known size of the cones distance of the cones from the vehicle.
3. 1 camera and 1 lidar. The cones will have different colors so that we must have a camera that will sync with the lidar which might be difficult and cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to first have a thorough check of past works done by various FS teams, one such example is [AMZ Driverless: The Full Autonomous Racing System](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.05150):

> The aforementioned ground removal algorithm removes a substantial amount of cone points in addition to those of the ground. This significantly reduces the already small number of return points that can be used to detect and identify cones. This is addressed by first clustering the point cloud after ground removal using Euclidean-distance based clustering algorithm and then reconstructing a cylindrical area around each cluster
> center using points from the point cloud before ground removal. This recovers most of the falsely removed points improving cone detection and color estimation (see Figure 9). The reconstructed clusters are then passed through a rule-based filter

Ideally I would go for a fourth option of using only Lidar and based on intensity values , differentiate the left and right cone. The pros are no hassle to sync different sources and lesser things to mount meaning lower weight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an assortment of depth cameras, which bundles along a number of different camera sensors which would help you perceive your environment in multiple domains.

For example, if you use a [RealSense D455](https://www.intelrealsense.com/depth-camera-d455/), you can use the RGB camera to check for the colour of the cones, and use the imagers to obtain a depth profile of the image. This will give you the distance of the detected cone from your robot. You can access the data quite easily with the help of their SDK, which is available in both C++ and Python.

Note that since your application is going to be a formula car, you might want to look at solutions which capture and process the data at a higher speed, something like the [Stereolabs Zed X](https://www.stereolabs.com/zed-x/), but usually these would require you to have a GPU on your formula car.